# Join on Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

i'm trying to do a query on hql hibernate (version 3.5.3), the query includes several joins between different tables (4 tables). This is the query:

```
     SELECT (lot of stuff) 
     FROM InvestigationRule as ir
     JOIN InvestigationFormula as if ON (ir.tb33InvestigationFormula=if.idInvestigationFormula) 
     JOIN InvestigationEvent as ie ON (ir.tb27InvestigationEvent=ie.idInvestigationEvent) 
     JOIN InvestigationSectionEvent as ise ON (ie.eventSection=ise.sectionEventsCod)
```

I met a syntax error on first ON, can someone help me fix this, thx.

ps: i know that i can make joins even without using the JOIN command, this is the original query:

```
    SELECT (lot of stuff)  
    FROM InvestigationRule AS ir, 
         InvestigationEvent as ie, 
         InvestigationSectionEvent as ise, 
         InvestigationFormula as if 
          WHERE ir.dateValidityEnd is null 
          AND ir.tb27InvestigationEvent = ie.idInvestigationEvent 
          AND ir.tb33InvestigationFormula = if.idInvestigationFormula 
          AND ie.eventSection = ise.sectionEventsCod
```

But i cannot use this form since it creates several CROSS JOIN(s) on the MySql database and this is not good.

Comment: if is a keyword in SQL. And also what you have is not HQL. It is SQL

Comment: In brief, properly model your entities and you shouldn't do joins like that.  Anyway, latest version of Hibernate does provide this kind of arbitrary join but I won't recommend using it unless necessary.  It is just ruining the whole idea of using ORM which you should make up a proper entity model

Comment: Show us the Hibernate entities mapping these tables.

Answer (score 2):

`if` is a keyword in SQL so you have to Change the alias:

```
SELECT (lot of stuff) 
     FROM InvestigationRule as ir
     JOIN InvestigationFormula as iform ON (ir.tb33InvestigationFormula=iform.idInvestigationFormula) 
     JOIN InvestigationEvent as ie ON (ir.tb27InvestigationEvent=ie.idInvestigationEvent) 
     JOIN InvestigationSectionEvent as ise ON (ie.eventSection=ise.sectionEventsCod)
```

HQL Looks like:

```
SELECT (lot of stuff) 
     FROM InvestigationRule ir
     JOIN ir tb33InvestigationFormula iform
     JOIN ir.tb27InvestigationEvent ie 
     JOIN  ie.eventSection ise
```

Comment: I changed the alias but i met the same problem on the ON. ps: it's hql not sql °W°

Comment: @Removed Do not think it is the same error. In HQL you have not to write on. You have to work with the properties not with column names

Comment: I tried to make the query without using JOIN (the second query that i wrote here) but it makes CROSS JOIN(s) on the database and i should avoid this.